# In an array, get string which begins with an specific character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m trying to get a single string from my array, that begins with 'c'.
With the following jQuery-Snippet, I´m able to check if a string with 'c' exists whether or not:

The Array (classes) contains: ["aLabel", "c2"]

c2 could also be c1, c3, c4, c5...

```
        var classes = $(this).parent().attr('class').split(' ');
        var found = $.inArray('c2', classes) > -1;
        console.log(classes);
        console.log(found);
```

I need the entire class c1, c2, ...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: So have you tried using [`$.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) or just writing a simple for loop to iterate through the array? What if the array has more than one element beginning with "c"?

Comment: There is alway one "c"-class in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you were using jQuery, you could do this as well:

```
var arr = [ "aghtrt", "acrt", "c2", "cwe4", "mklp", "c1", "hello", "world" ],
    matches = new Array();

matches = $.grep(arr, function( n, i ) {
    return (n.search(/^c/i) > -1) ? true : false;
});

$("p").text(matches.join(", "));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bc51b4wo/

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is just to iterate through the array, testing each element to see if it matches:

```
function getStringBeginningWith(arr, firstChar) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].charAt(0) === firstChar) {
      return arr[i];
    }
  }
  return ""; // return whatever default value applies if no elements match
}

// then, elsewhere in your code:
var classes = $(this).parent().attr('class').split(' ');
var className = getStringBeginningWith(classes, "c");
if (className != "") {
  // matching class found, so do something
}
```

You said in a comment that there would only ever be one matching class, but if there were more than one the function I've written would just return the first.

Answer (score 0):

All you want just need,there is no need to split the string to an Array

```
/\bc/ig.test('a c')
```